# SQL Server - Max Date for multiple records & related data

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, maxdate

I have 1900 locations that I am trying to find the max(date) that an order was placed.  And also the order cost and order quantity for that related location/date.

How do I build a sub-query or join in order to retrieve this data.

Example attempt below:

```
    select table1.location, table2.ord_dt, table2.order_cost, table2.order_qty
    from table2
    join table 3 on table2.id1 = table3.id1
    join table 1 on table1.id1 = table3.id2
    where table2.ord_dt = (
    select table1.location, max(table2.ord_dt)
    from table2
    join table 3 on table2.id1 = table3.id1
    join table 1 on table1.id1 = table3.id2
    group by table1.location
```

I'm sure my logic is off plus I'm getting a "Number of elements on each side of a predicate operator does not match" error.  Probably because I need more columns in my main query than I'm pulling in my sub-query.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: are you using MSSQL ?

Comment: @Backtrack The title and tag indicate yes, unless the OP is very confused, which I'm sure isn't true :-)

Comment: Can you add some sample records for each table and the output you would expect the sample to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte(location, odate) as 
(

   select table1.location, max(table2.ord_dt)
    from table2
    join table 3 on table2.id1 = table3.id1
    join table 1 on table1.id1 = table3.id2
    group by table1.location
)
select table1.location, table2.ord_dt, table2.order_cost, table2.order_qty
    from table2
    join table 3 on table2.id1 = table3.id1
    join table 1 on table1.id1 = table3.id2
    join cte on cte.location =  table1.location and cte.odate = table2.ord_dt
order by 
table1.location, table2.ord_dt, table2.order_cost, table2.order_qty
```

if you are using **MSSQL**, you can use `CTE`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server.  More specifically I'm building a data flow task via SSIS package.

Comment: I would like to see |store 1| 6/13/2016 | $200 | 245.... being location | max date the store placed an order | cost of order | quantity of order

Comment: @rashaad_hannah, Added order by. It will give you the result